# jquery: vertically expand div when using contained draggable

Tags: jquery, css

I've got paragraphs of plain text with specific words hilited. the hilited words are meant to be draggable. when dragging is started, i want the div that hilites the word (#hilite) to expand top and bottom extents (vertically only), in a higher z-order, and allow the word (#word) to be dragged up and down in that space (container: parent). The plans is at some point have it dropped on a droppable within the area.

at this point, my problem is that i expand #hilite with padding... which increases the size of the div without increasing usable space. Would using Resizable be better? or Animate? I've seen a number of recommendations for using Resizable, but i thought it was for user resizing not programmatic.

for the droppables, i figure that once the space is created i'll swap out .css('display', '[none|block]') to show them inside the #hilite div and make them valid targets.

http://jsfiddle.net/monsto/GCsnM/ for what i have atm.

*(oh btw, i hate the people came up with jsfiddle. it's simply **too genius.**)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you want to do, but if you have `#word` draggable with a containment of parent, which is `#hilite`, nothing moves. and `'vertically'` isn't a proper parameter for draggable, instead use `'x'` or `'y'`.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GCsnM/9/

Answer (score 0):

Your container is a span, which is by default an inline element, it cannot show block properites. You have to tell it behave as block

```css
#hilite { display: inline-block; }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GCsnM/12/)

And the options you gave `vertically` is false, give `Y`. <sup>[Read Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-axis)</sup>